# Conditional Execution in Same View

Tags: django, if-statement, django-views, conditional-statements

I want my declarations to be user-specific.
I chose to do this by making my variable declarations in the view conditional based on user-type.
Here's a sample.

```
def order_detail(request, order_id):
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=order_id)

    if request.user.is_supervisor:
        user_location = request.user.supervisor.town
    deliverer = User.objects.filter(deliverer__town=user_location)

    context={
        'order': order,
        'all_delivery_guys_in_town': deliverer
        }
    template = 'orders/order_mgt/detail.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

For context, I need supervisors to be able to view a list of available delivery guys within the order detail page.

In the code sample, I'm getting an error:

```
local variable 'user_location' referenced before assignment
```

**1. How can I correct this error?**

**2. Is there a better way of making conditional declarations within the same view?**

Comment: You define a value for `user_location` when `request.user.is_supervisor` does not hold?

Comment: The problem is that you here run this with a `user` that is not `.is_supervisor`, hence `user_location` is not set, and thus you filter with `delivered = User.objects.filter(...)`, but that is not possible since at that time `user_location` has no value.

Comment: Is it possible to have a lazy definition where the execution is only facilitated for the relevant user?

Comment: but what would the semantics be then. Imagine that you later *use* the `all_delivery_guys_in_town` variable (for example in your template), then what should be the result?

Comment: Do I then, have to define separate detail pages for different user_types? Is it not possible to use a conditional for such a problem?

Comment: it is often better to make separate views. It also makes authorization easier: you can write a decorator that prevents people from accessing a certain view if they are not a supervisor, which makes it simpler and less error-prone.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this fails is because if the `request.user.is_supervisor` fails, then `user_location` is not set, but you use this when you `.filter(…)` the `User`s. You can filter in the if-clause as well and for example work with `User.objects.none()` (an empty queryset) when the user is not a supervisor:

```
def order_detail(request, order_id):
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=order_id)

    if request.user.is_supervisor:
        user_location = request.user.supervisor.town
        deliverer = User.objects.filter(deliverer__town=user_location)
    else:
        delivered = User.objects.none()

    context={
        'order': order,
        'all_delivery_guys_in_town': deliverer
    }
    template = 'orders/order_mgt/detail.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```